# Parsing and splitting multiple HTML pages without having a clue

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing, data-mining

I have the some 50 raw HTML page contents which are relevant to my project. I am not sure these contents are having unique pattern.

I need to parse the contents from all pages and has to be classified based on the keywords.

Keywords all like that

**'REVIEWS',"REPORTS","FEEDBACK","DESCRIPTION","COMMENTS","SUCCESS RATES","FAILURE RATES"**

The crawled HTML content has to be classified and **mapped to the relevant keywords**.

Also need to be split the contents and it's headers from the page for comparison

I am using Python.

Would you please suggest the way to do this? Which will be suitable to choose? How the idea has to be organised?

Comment: are these `keywords` html tags.?

Comment: show us an example of your html snippet.

Comment: @RanRag The keywords are not html tags.These keywords will be placed inside html header tag.Based on the header matching we need to track the following data.

Comment: @RanRang For example "http://www.healthproductreviews.com/" in this URL we have the header "REview" ,So we need to track their following reviews.

Comment: Similarly for this url "http://www.dailystrength.org/search?q=prozac" i need to track all the comments for that keyword prozac

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical classification problem. You could use a bayesian classifier to identify what category a page belongs to. This would allow you to easily scale the sites you are following easily.

Check out 
http://www.python-course.eu/text_classification_introduction.php

For a general introduction. What I'd really recommend is a book called programming collective intelligence from O'Reilly, the book examples are in python and they have a chapter dedicated to what you are trying to do. They don't go into significant detail but enough to get you up and running.

IF you just want to explore how to identify the pages etc. Try Weka which is a java based tool. Obviously this doesn't match your python requirements so I'd suggest it more as a learning tool if you are interested in the general area.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do classification given the content of pages, I would suggest you to take a look at NLTK (http://www.nltk.org/), a natural language toolkit of open source python modules.

Don't just try to look at occurrences of e.g. "report" in the the pages. A report may or may not have "report" as a title or in the content. You can use NLTK to find terms related to your keywords (e.g. success rates vs. approval rates), or from the same family (e.g. description vs. described).

Take a look at the pages' contents and try to define what sets them apart from the others. For instance, a page with comments will probably have expressions such as "I think that", "in my opinion" and subjective terms, usually adjectives and adverbs, like "good", "quickly", "horrible", etc. A report is unlikely to have such words in it.

Apart from the content, the structure of the page may vary from category to category. If you intend to analyse that, maybe using Beautiful Soup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing is a good idea.